# Node JS query MongoDB for key regex or wildcard?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, wildcard

Hello I am learning NodeJS and have a simple swagger API to retrieve sports statistics from mongodb and present them in json format. My document store looks a bit like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/grx1N.jpg

The key  indicates a date at which a game was played, for example 217010700 is 07/01/2017 and then 00 01 02 indicates the number of the game that date.

I have a function which retrieves one specific game successfully which looks like:

```
function test(req, res) {
  var stats = db.get().collection('stats');
  stats.find({},{"2017010700":1}).toArray(function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results[0])
  });
}
```

What I want to do is something like this to retrieve all games from 2017, where * being some wildcard type thing, but I am unsure how to do this with javascript or mongodb:

```
function test(req, res) {
  var result = [];
  var stats = db.get().collection('stats');
  stats.find({},{"2017*":1}).toArray(function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results[0])
  });
}
```

Comment: You should move the game date into its own field so you can query it.

Comment: Can you paste 2 documents from your collection in MongoDB? My first guess is that the Key:Value pair is not used appropriately but I would like to be sure.